# How to return from STRING_AGG to regular table?

Tags: sql-server

I used STRING_AGG function to aggregate strings in a row. Now I need to do something reverse - every string (in a given row) turns into a row. Here is a basic example:

This is what I got now (using STRING_AGG):

```
SELECT
STRING_AGG(t.names,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.some_value) as aggr_string,
t.some_value
FROM dbo.Tbl t
GROUP BY t.some_value
```

| aggr_string | some_value |
| --- | --- |
| car; bike | 250 |
| house; dog | 3900 |

and this is what I want to achieve:

| aggr_string | some_value |
| --- | --- |
| car | 250 |
| bike | 250 |
| house | 3900 |
| dog | 3900 |

Is there any way to make it possible? Have no idea how to do it. I'm using SQL Server 2019

Comment: Hi, please provide https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it will help to find solution. Also, please specify which sql you're working with.

Comment: you need to tag your dbms

Comment: "*I'm using SQL Server 2020*" Are you sure? The latest version at the time of writing is SQL Server 2019...

Comment: Yes, my mistake :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are on sql server 2016+ :

```
select s.value , t.some_value
from yourtable t
cross apply (select value from string_split(aggr_string,';')) s
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!